# Break promise map from within function value?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

In this example code below you can see that I have a chain of functions that are getting mapped, and when and when the error is thrown the chain is exited. The value of the global `x` is set to `bar` from the first function but it's not set to `baz` from the third because it never runs.

```
var x = "foo"

Promise.map([
  function(){
    x = "bar"
    return true
  },
  function(){
    throw new Error()
  },
  function(){
    x = "baz"
    return true
  }
], function(fn){
  return Promise.method(fn)()
})
.catch(function(e){
  console.log(e) // [Error]
})
.then(function(){
  console.log(x) // "bar"
})
```

However when I open up the promise within the map function and interject a conditionally thrown error `x` is changed to `baz`, and the third function does run.

```
var x = "foo"

Promise.map([
  function(){
    x = "bar"
    return true
  },
  function(){
    return "bad value throw error"
  },
  function(){
    x = "baz"
    return true
  }
], function(fn){
  return Promise.method(fn)().then(function(val){
    if(val == "bad value throw error") throw new Error()
    return val
  })
})
.catch(function(e){
  console.log(e) // [Error]
})
.then(function(){
  console.log(x) // "baz"
})
```

How can I interject an error in the promise map and throw that error breaking the map chain?

Is there another bluebird method that can run an array of promises in series?

Comment: If you want to run the functions in *parallel*, why would you expect them to stop running even before an error has been thrown?

Comment: That's a typo I want them to run in series.

Comment: Yeah, then use the `{concurrency: 1}` option.

Comment: @Bergi I tried that [here are the tests](https://gist.github.com/reggi/fe3c8fba9c536c83f9a6) here's the [issue in bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/705#issuecomment-122559783)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is to use `each` instead of `map`.

```
var x = "foo"

Promise.each([
  function(){
    x = "bar"
    return true
  },
  function(){
    return "bad value throw error"
  },
  function(){
    x = "baz"
    return true
  }
], function(fn){
  return Promise.method(fn)().then(function(val){
    if(val == "bad value throw error") throw new Error()
    return val
  })
})
.catch(function(e){
  console.log(e) // [Error]
})
.then(function(){
  console.log(x) // "baz"
})
```

Comment: Could you explain why using `each` instead of `map` ?